# Why wont this command work 1.11

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a armor stand named 1a

```
/execute @r[type=Armor_Stand,name:1a] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~ redstone_block
```

When I try to execute it, I get the error message:

> Invalid selector argument: 'name:1a'

What is wrong with the command?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, and what is the error (if you are even getting one at all)?

Comment: This is the error

Comment: [19:10:27] Invalid selector argument: 'name:1a'

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you have a `:` rather than a `=` between `name` and `1a`. The fixed command should be:

```
/execute @r[type=Armor_Stand,name=1a] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~ redstone_block
```

Comment: Shouldn't the fixed command be ...`name=1a`... because of the fix?

Comment: @SeeOneRhino Woops, copy-pasted it then forgot to do the fix.

Comment: @user173621 If you found the answer helpful, you should click the accept button